# MongoDB - Downside to having different documents on same collection?

Tags: mongodb

**What are the downsides of storing completely different documents on the same collection of MongoDB?**

Unlike others questions, the documents I'm referring to are not related (like parent-child).

The motivator here is cost-reduction. Azure CosmosDB Mongo API charges and scalability are per-collection.

Comment: Is your development time free?

Comment: hehehehe not free, but the current operational cost is around $4/hour using minimal scale, zero data and no replication or fancy features! $2900/month where I live, due to exchange rate, that's really expensive!

Comment: Seems like a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The size of the collection will get a lot bigger a lot faster.
- Speed of queries could be impacted as you'll have to scan more documents than required (could maybe use sparse indexes)
- Index sizes will be a lot bigger and longer to scan
- You'll need to store a discriminator with the documents so you can tell what type one document is compared to another.

If the documents are not related at all, I'd store them in completely separate collections.

Comment: I agree on most points except index size where you can create a sparse index which will work just fine.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I was thinking more of 2 unrelated documents with the same fields, and if you end up with an index on { discriminator, other-field } then you'll end up with a much bigger index.